# IzPack error : Invalid base directory on jenkins-ci

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, izpack

first I am not sure if this question belong here or on serverfault.
I am using IzPack for our project. Everything is working fine on my local machine. Unfortunately on my jenkins I have the following error:

```
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] com.izforge.izpack.api.exception.CompilerException: Invalid base directory: /root/.jenkins/jobs/installer-izpack/workspace/target/staging
```

I am using:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
<artifactId>izpack-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0-beta8</version>
```

The jenkins is installed on a debian squeeze.
When i log remotely on the server and verify the target/ directory the jar created from maven is there but there is no "staging" directory. In my honest opinion i think the problem is that jenkins is unable to create the stagging repository. As usual thank you for your time.

How I proceed: I am building some other jar (other jenkins job), then launch the installer to package everything. I don't know if this is enough information. If you need more information or if something is not clear enough please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a permission problem, be sure that jenkins have the permission to create the stagging directory.